# Change icon for recorded activity from custom app in History list

Tags: connectiq, monkeyc

I have made my own Connect IQ app for my Garmin Forerunner watch. I have changed the LauncherIcon to my own image instead of the default IQ-icon.

My app uses ActivityRecording so the activity can be saved to the list of activities in History. However, in this list the icon for the activity is just "IQ".

Is it possible to change this to a custom image? Otherwise, I won't be able to tell the activities from custom apps apart.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the icon used for activities recorded by ConnectIQ apps.